# Ways to set up a video as a background 'image'

Tags: css, flash

I need to set up a website with a video as the background.

Will I be able to use `z-index` to position other elements on top of the video?  Is there a better alternative?

Comment: is it not correct? i'm spanish.. I've been asked? :P

Comment: "They" is rarely used unless it is clear who "they" are.  If you'd said, "I just spoke to the people in charge, and they asked me..." then that would have been correct, as it is understood who "they" are -- "the people in charge."  It doesn't make it seem as though you are bad at English, but it is a little out of the ordinary... one interpretation of failing to identify who "they" are might be that you have so much contempt for "them" that you don't even want to identify who "they" are.

Comment: so, i ask again. is better "I've been asked if.." ?

Comment: "I've been asked if I could" or "I've been asked to" would have been fine.  Don't feel bad about it... lol... everyone understood what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested it, but you could try to set width/height of `<video>` to `100%` then using z-index let all the others element stay on top of it...

Edit:
for example to set video as background entire page

```
<body style="height: 100%;width: 100%">
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1;">
 <video src="" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay>
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>
... rest of your site
```

Comment: http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp btw for ie is not supported, but you can use ogg for firefox and opera, MPEG4 for safari, chrome accept both

Answer (score 2):

You can not apply it as a CSS background (background property). You can give the effect though using layers which is controlled via the z-index property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flash as your video playing method no - flash is ALWAYS on top of anything regardless of z-index, But I imagine this could be done by using the new HTML5 `<video>` tag.

Failing that convert to a high-frame rate animated image and set as BG...

Comment: -1 "flash is ALWAYS on top of anything" - wrong. If you use wmode=transparent you can position your flash on any z-index and allow rendering above or below the flash container.

Comment: Ah thanks for this, I was unaware, I was always told flash would disregard z-index.

Comment: Damp, is it posible that wmode=transparent loads a lot CPU?

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet - yes - there are various reported bugs on different OSs that report increased CPU load while the setting is turned on.

Comment: Anything that is CPU/System intensive while another more lightweight option is available should generally not be considered or advised upon.